# OSB "The dependency mapping is not configured in WSDL resource"

Tags: xsd, wsdl, weblogic, osb

I'm using **Oracles Service Bus (OSB)** and I'm trying to use an **XSD** in my **WSDL** that has the following schemaLocation in its XSD import:

```
schemaLocation="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/br-2.xsd"
```

My problem is that OSB is not able to resolve this dependency and gives me error :

`"The dependency mapping is not configured in WSDL resource"`.

I'm able to do a work around by importing the **XSD** into the **OSB** project and use a relative path to the resource `(schemaLocation="../myXSDs/br-2.xsd")`, but I don't want relative paths, especially when I shouldn't need one.

So how can I use an URL directly as an **XSD** resource in **OSB**? and if not, why? Security reasons??

my software stack is as follows:

**OSB (version 11.1.1.7.0)**

**OEPE (11.1.1.7.0) (inc. Weblogic Server 10.3.6.0)**

Friendly regards from a service oriented developer :-)

Comment: It sounds like you have to upload the xsd, external references are not allowed. Check out the following link: https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2423314